# JS: Click h1 to set display to none at another div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm very new in scripting with js. My question is, how can i set an onclick at an h1, which set the display to none at another div?

Here my code:

var iter;

```
        function toggleGroups()
        {
            function getAllGroups()
            {
                titlebars = document.getElementsByClassName('titlebar_js');
                groupfields = document.getElementsByClassName('inner_groups_gether');
                for(i = 0; i < titlebars.length;i++)
                {
                    tb = titlebars[i];
                    iter = i;
                    tb.onclick = function()
                    {
                        alert(iter);
                        groupfields[iter].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }           
            getAllGroups();
        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
            toggleGroups(); // Aufruf der Funktion
        }
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, the other guy is right, jQuery is great for solving this very quickly. Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).bind("load", function() { 
            $('h1').click(function() {
                $('div.toBeHidden').css('display','none');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<h1>Click me!</h1>
<div class="toBeHidden">
    This block will be hidden after clicking the h1... 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here you are telling the browser to grab any h1 tag and make the divs with class "toBeHidden" to disappear.

You can learn bout jQuery [here](http://jquery.com/). It is worth it for sure. I rarely use pure javascript again after having started with jQuery.

Comment: Not adequate: the asker wants each `h1` to hide its respective `div`, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You really should look at a javascript library such as [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: -1: This is too vague to be useful. A link to an example of something similar to what was requested that uses jQuery, fine, but this isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have trapped into a common JS closure bug. Try this:

```
tb.onclick = function(val) {
                    return function() {
                    alert(val);
                    groupfields[val].style.display = 'none'; }
                }(iter);
```

Here you can read more about using closures and event handlers:
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg36/

Answer (score 1):

```
    function toggleGroups()
    {
        var titlebars = document.getElementsByClassName('titlebar_js'),
            groupfields = document.getElementsByClassName('inner_groups_gether'),
            tLength = titlebars.length,
            tb, iter;

        while (tLength--)
        {
            tb = titlebars[tLength];
            iter = tLength;
            tb.onclick = function(iter)
            {
                return function() 
                {
                    alert(iter);
                    groupfields[iter].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }(iter);
        }
    }
    window.onload = function()
    {
        toggleGroups(); // Aufruf der Funktion
    }
```